# Adding prefix to values meeting a condition(s) in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

So I've been searching high and low for anything similar to this topic. I'm trying to add a prefix to my data values meeting a criteria from another column.

I'm, using `dplyr` and `data.table`.

So for example I have this data frame, `df1`, which has these columns.

```
Program | Violation
-------------------
CACF    |  SV-300
CACF    |  SV-101
DCH     |  SV-205
DCH     |  SV-302
CACF    |  SV-403
DCH     |  SV-302
```

I want to add DCH- in front of the Violation ID number and not mutate another column. I want to do this to the existing column so that my existing `df1` can look like this.

```
Program | Violation
-------------------
CACF    |  SV-300
CACF    |  SV-101
DCH     |  DCH-SV-205
DCH     |  DCH-SV-302
CACF    |  SV-403
DCH     |  DCH-SV-302
```

I have been trying the paste0 function but no avail.

```
df1$Violation = paste0("DCH-"), df1$Program == "DCH"
```

I'm still relatively new to R and have been googling and looking around on how to do this. I'm sure its super simple but I cannot find a thread with the similar concept I'm looking for. If there is one please link it.

Comment: Is it only that one case (i.e. when Program == "DCH") you need to change?

Comment: share data with `dput()`.

Comment: @camille Yes, it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The `data.table` way**:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
df1[Program == "DCH", Violation := paste0(Program, "-", Violation)]
df1
   Program  Violation
1:    CACF     SV-300
2:    CACF     SV-101
3:     DCH DCH-SV-205
4:     DCH DCH-SV-302
5:    CACF     SV-403
6:     DCH DCH-SV-302
```

**Or base R:**

```
df1[["Violation"]] <- 
  with(df1, ifelse(Program == "DCH", paste0(Program, "-", Violation), Violation))

df1

  Program  Violation
1    CACF     SV-300
2    CACF     SV-101
3     DCH DCH-SV-205
4     DCH DCH-SV-302
5    CACF     SV-403
6     DCH DCH-SV-302
```

Where

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  Program = c("CACF", "CACF", "DCH", "DCH", "CACF", "DCH"), 
  Violation = c("SV-300", "SV-101", "SV-205", "SV-302", "SV-403", "SV-302"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Comment: Thanks, for adding base on there too it! I tried it just to see. It worked. Thanks a lot again! @snoram

Answer (score 3):

We can use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(Violation = case_when(Program == "DCH" ~ paste0("DCH-", Violation), 
                         TRUE ~ Violation))
```

Comment: I did it this way and for some reason the result worked but instead of keeping the same SV codes it would change the DCH codes to V-0000 for every occurrence

Comment: @Roy do you have a `factor` class for the column.  In that case change it to `character` i.e. `TRUE ~ as.character(Violation)`

Comment: Forget it, stupid me. I was looking at the wrong columns, It worked! thanks @akrun for the fast response!

Comment: Akrun, can I ask one thing more. so what if I had NAs in my Violation column, how would i keep the DCH from appearing by itself on the column

Comment: I added a second criteria to keep my NAs and only add "DCH-" to the actual values but it doesn't add "DCH-" in front of the ones that meet the criteria, what am I doing wrong?  `df1 %>%
   mutate(Violation = case_when(Program == "DCH" & Violation != NA ~ paste0("DCH-", Violation), 
                         TRUE ~ Violation))`

Comment: @Roy You need `Program == "DCH" & !is.na(Program)`

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using the `dplyr` answer by @akrun.
It may be preferable sometimes to use "Base R"

**Data:**

```
df1 <-
  read.table(text = "
Program, Violation
CACF,SV-300
CACF,SV-101
DCH,SV-205
DCH,SV-302
CACF,SV-403
DCH,SV-302", sep = ",",
           header = T,
           stringsAsFactors = F)
```

**Solution:**
Use standard indexing to select the cases to modify: 1) filter the row based on your condition and 2) select the column

```
df1[df1$Program=="DCH", "Violation"] <- # select the row and column using indexing [row, col]
  paste0("DCH-", df1[df1$Program=="DCH", "Violation"])

df1
  Program  Violation
1    CACF     SV-300
2    CACF     SV-101
3     DCH DCH-SV-205
4     DCH DCH-SV-302
5    CACF     SV-403
6     DCH DCH-SV-302
```

Comment: Thanks, I did the way @akrun mentioned, I'll keep this in mind too, thanks man!

Comment: If you are starting out, I recommend learning the `tidyverse` syntax (see the "R for Data Science" book online), and then compare with the Base R version. In some situations the Base R version may be preferable.